# Unity: I’m looking for a way to compare the speeds of two gameObjects on colliding

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, compare, collision-detection

I’m looking for a way to compare the speeds of two gameObjects on colliding. So if the speed of the object is faster than the object it has collided with it ApplysBreak. However when I try and access the variables for speed for each gameobject I get a null reference.

Well what I’m trying to do is have cars travelling on the road. The cars have a trigger at the front and a hitbox at the back of the cars. What I want to happen is when the trigger hits the hitbox it compares the Variables for speed of the two cars in the collision, i.e. the make the car at the back slow down or equal the speed of the car in the front. However, what I am having trouble with is referencing the speed of both cars and comparing them. This is due to them both being prefabs using the same script.  Which I’m learning means that I’m just referencing the same script and not the actual values of the individual car.

```cs
private void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    Debug.Log("TriggerStay");

    Traffic Col_speed = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Traffic>();

    if (speed > Col_speed.speed)
    {
        Accelerate = false;
        ApplyBreak = true;
    }
    else if (speed< Col_speed.speed)
    {
        Accelerate = false;
        ApplyBreak = false;
        speed = Col_speed.speed;
    }
}
```

Comment: tbh  didnt know the collision class had a speed.. rigidbodies do though

Comment: I want to access the variable 'speed' from the collision objects script.

Comment: Then get the instance of the script from the game object

Comment: How would you about this?

Comment: Check the tag of what is being collided with? Is your `OnTriggerStay()` firing on the ground or something?

Comment: Well what I’m trying to do is have cars travelling on the road. The cars have a trigger at the front and a hitbox at the back of the cars. What I want to happen is when the trigger hits the hitbox it compares the Variables for speed of the two cars in the collision, i.e. the make the car at the back slow down or equal the speed of the car in the front. However, what I am having trouble with is referencing the speed of both cars and comparing them. This is due to them both being prefabs using the same script.

Comment: Which I’m learning means that I’m just referencing the same script and not the actual values of the individual car.

Comment: Ok. So it looks like your new version should be working better.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the collision and not the trigger, then the 'collision' passed in to the `OnCollisionEnter()` function has a property `Impulse`, which gives you an idea of the difference in speed. It also has a `GetContact()` to find where exactly the touched.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision.html

With triggers, it is a little different. You need to calculate the speed of the items on the collisionpoint. Trouble is, that the OnTriggerEnter() and OnTriggerStay() methods do not supply contact points.

If you items are of similar size, you could simply assume the point in the middle to be the contact point, then calc the speed on these. Use the Rigidbody2D's velocity and angularVelocity to do this. If your objects have a simple shape, such as rectangular cars, you might make some own code to figure out a more useful contactpoint.

The code in the this sample assumes a simple contact point in the middle of the two items and then calculates the velocity of both ends of it. If you are not using Rigidbody2D on the same object, but in some parent, you might need to change this a little. When getting a rigidbody from a parent, be careful to use the transform.position of the same gameObject that has the rigidbody, not the one that has the collider!

```
using UnityEngine;

public class TriggerHitSpeed : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector3 hit_v1;
    public Vector3 hit_v2;
    private Rigidbody2D rgb;

    private void Start()
    {
        rgb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        if(rgb==null)
            Destroy(this);
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        Vector3 hitpoint;

        // unlike OnCollisionEnter2D(), trigger functions don't get a contact point
        // simply assume middle of centers. For a CollisionEnter, can use the contact point from the collision.
        hitpoint = (collision.transform.position+transform.position)*0.5f;
        // speed of self at hitpoint
        Vector3 rotspeed;
        Vector3 v1,v2;
        Vector2 speed;
        if(rgb!=null)
        {
            rotspeed = Vector3.forward * rgb.angularVelocity*Mathf.Deg2Rad;  // for 3D object, use angularVelocity directly.
            speed = rgb.velocity;
            v1 = Vector3.Cross( rotspeed , hitpoint-transform.position );
            v1 += new Vector3(speed.x,speed.y,0f);
        }else
            v1 = Vector3.zero;
        // speed of other at hitpoint
        if(collision.attachedRigidbody!=null)
        {
            rotspeed = Vector3.forward * collision.attachedRigidbody.angularVelocity*Mathf.Deg2Rad;// for 3D object, use     angularVelocity directly.
            speed = collision.attachedRigidbody.velocity;
            v2 = Vector3.Cross( rotspeed , hitpoint-collision.transform.position );
            v2 += new Vector3(speed.x,speed.y,0f);
        }else
            v2 = Vector3.zero;

        // can now look at the difference and do something with it.
        //   v2-v1;
        // [...]
        hit_v1 = v1;
        hit_v2 = v2;

    }
}
```

The code that considers the rotation makes it nicer and more pricise, in case your cars are spinning out of control and then hit someone, bumping him sideways.